# Cloud functions crash with `Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.`

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cloud

We have some Cloud functions to send notifications to users. (and others that calculates other stuff). All these CF are using the Realtime database , that is where we are hosting all the data.

But few days ago, we added new functions that sincronize Realtime database to a new table in Firestore (due to migration of db process)

And I think here is the problem. We detect that some pushes are not being sended to users,some data is not being writed in the proper tables... and taking a look to the Log of the functions we get this:

```
Error: Can't determine Firebase Database URL.
    at FirebaseDatabaseError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at new FirebaseDatabaseError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:202:23)
    at DatabaseService.ensureUrl (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:88:15)
    at DatabaseService.getDatabase (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:55:26)
    at FirebaseApp.database (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:231:24)
    at FirebaseNamespace.fn (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:280:45)
    at exports.sendCommunityMessageNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/srv/index.js:348:49)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
```

But I don't know, what I have to do, or modify , because I didn't found any solution

Here is a little example of the new function, and an older one that stopped working.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firestore = admin.firestore();

//NEW FUNCTION
exports.createUpToOnFirestore = functions.database.ref('/upto/{uptoId}').onCreate((snap,context) => {
.....
  return firestore.collection('uptos')
                  .doc(uptoId)
                  .set(json)
}

//OLD FUNCTION
    exports.sendInvitationCreated = functions.database.ref('/invitation/{invitationId}')
    .onCreate((snap,context) => {
    .....
    ...
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(userList).length; i++) {
          const user = users[i];
          const userValue = usersValues[i];

          if (userValue === 3){ //Value 3 means user is Admin
            adminUserId = user;
          }
          console.log('Getting promise of user uid=',user);
          console.log('adminUserId=',adminUserId);
    //HERE IS WHERE THE FUNCTIONS CRASH
          AllFollowersFCMPromises[numberNotifications] = admin.database().ref(`/user/${user}/`).once('value');
          numberNotifications = numberNotifications+ 1;
      }
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the following environment variables?

- `GCLOUD_PROJECT="projectId"`
- `GCLOUD_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="service_account.json"`
- `FIREBASE_CONFIG="firebase_config.json"`

The service account has to be generated in the gcloud.

The *firebase_config.json* takes the following form:

```
{  
  "databaseURL": "https://projectId.firebaseio.com",
  "projectId": "projectId",
  "storageBucket": "gs://projectId.appspot.com"
}
```

If you want to know more about how to initialize the `admin` object without worrying about the configuration read the following article:
[Firebase Separating Configuration From Code](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-separating-configuration-from-code-in-admin-sdk-d2bcd2e87de6)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and after deep research, the problem was from the "firebase-functions" import.

This error will happen if you imported firebase-functions after calling admin.initializeApp();

So to fix it you have to import "firebase-functions" first before initializing, like this

```
//import firebase-functions first to avoid the issue
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//then initialize
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I specified the credential object while initializing the admin sdk

```
admin.initializeApp({credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()});
```

This worked locally, but lead to a crash when I tried to execute the deployed function.
When I removed specifying the credentail object it worked.
I changed it as

```
admin.initializeApp()
```